# TLS certificate on a production server

Tags: security, ssl, web, ssl-certificate

I need to deploy my application on a server provided by my company's client.
I want to serve pages through HTTPS, therefore I need a TLS certificate. My company's client already have other sites and uses certificates on them.

My question is: who usually provides this certificate? I'm a 99% sure that my company's client should do it but I want to be sure. If so, what do I need to ask for?

Thanks.

Comment: Often times, your company serves in the *host* role and either provides the certificate or sells the certificate to the client. Sometimes, the client provides their own certificate. Ask your company and the client what the policies are, and what you should do.

Comment: If the client already has other HTTPS servers _which they set up_ (as opposed to buying/renting/etc -- and you may not be able to tell this from outside) then they obviously know how to do it and presumably can do it for your server also. Depending on what type of webserver you (will) use, either give them a CSR for an agreed name (which may get overridden anyway) or a keypair they can use to generate a CSR; or accept a keypair they have used to generate the CSR; and in all cases accept the resulting cert chain.

Answer (score 1):

**If you have** access to your client's server and can receive emails like webmaster@domain.com or postmaster@domain.com, you can do the certificate purchase for him.

**If you can** create a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) from your client's  cPanel or WHM, you're all set.

**Now, from what I know... and without prejudice**, *(because this **may** vary from a Certification Authority(CA) to another, I don't know... And this is as march 2016)*

**There is 4 classes of certificates.**


**Class 1** is a self-signed certificate.
It is the most commonly used.
This is enought in most cases since encryption will be enabled.
The only validation made is to confirm an email like the one I cited above.
But for the main domain address only...
It is not including all its sub-domains.
You can manage multiple certs for additionnal sub-domains... But it gets complicated quite fast.

**Class 2** is a person certification.
It is needed to acquire class 3 and 4.
This one requires you to send a valid ID like a country passport to validate your identity.
AND (no joke!) a recent picture of you holding it in a good image resolution.

**Class 3** (also called **OV**) is the same thing as class 1 except it allows all sub-domains.
You will have to be named, via a letter from the CEO, as an autorized contact to act on their behalf.
Then, the organization or company has also to be autentified via a direct phone call to the CEO.

**Class 4** (also called **EV**) is the same as class 3, but the certificate shows like a nice very visible green bar with the name of the company in front of the url in the browsers address bar.
This one is only availaible to companies and legally registered organizations.


You can Google "Certificate Authority" to find a certificate emitter.
**CHECK the pricings !!**
There a lot differences between one and another.
;)


***As a hint for time it takes to implement:***
It took me like 4 hours on my first try for class 1.
   *(3 years ago... I was "slower" than now! If you're fast, it can take you 45 min.)*
It took me around 4 months to get the class 4 on my first try.
   *(I didn't have a passport! If you're fast, it could take you 2 weeks.)*

**For the record, by reading this**, you just saved 2 fulltime weeks reseaching on the differences between classes and the administrative process related. You probably wouldn't find all these details anyway... without really doing the request.
;)

Answer (score 0):

Work with the client to purchase a certificate. The provider will usually give you all the information you need to install it.

Be sure to update your server config to deliver HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to provide any information to my client in order to get this certificate purchased? Anything besides the common name of my server.

Comment: @ElAx servers don't have common names; certificates do, but this century they also have (subject) alternative names, abbreviated SAN. Whoever deals with the CA must provide the _domain names_, possibly more than one, of the server, and a CSR containing the publickey and signed by the privatekey, and evidence of domain control, and much more if they/you want EV. Although the CSR does carry a proposed common name, nowadays it is usually ignored.